# How to register reference to Qt containers?

Tags: c++, qt, types, pass-by-reference

I want to pass `QQueue<double>&` by a signal to a slot in another thread. I want to pass the queue by reference because i don't want the data to be copied when i change queue elements in the slot. So i should register this meta type to have QueuedConnection. When i register it like:

```
qRegisterMetaType<QQueue<double>& >("QQueue<double>&");
```

I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'qRegisterMetaType(const char [16])'
```

How should i register it?

Comment: why not pass a pointer?

Comment: I can not pass a pointer because in one thread i should collect data and in another one i should use it. The size of data is variant. One thread enqueues the other one dequeues.

Comment: And `connect(thr1, SIGNAL(signal(const QQueue<double>&)), thr2, SLOT(slot(const QQueue<double>&)));` does not work?

Comment: No. It gives the warning that can not queue arguments of that type and you should register it.

Comment: @Nejat that doesn't stop you from passing a pointer...

Comment: You mean passing a pointer to QQueue<double>? If that yeah you are right.

Comment: I don't think you can use references when using queued connections. If you use const reference, then [it will be copied anyway](http://www.embeddeduse.com/2013/06/29/copied-or-not-copied-arguments-signals-slots/).

Comment: So i think the only way to avoid copying on a queued connection is to pass a pointer to data type.

Comment: Looks like `QQueue` is missing a move constructor (I'd classify that as a bug), but if you used a `QList`, you could pass by value and use `emit mySignal(std::move(localContainerVar));` to avoid a copy. If you are using that as a mechanism to return value from the slot, then I'd advice against it, because it works differently, if you ever use for example a queued connection. I'd recommend passing a `QSharedPointer` to heap allocated `QQueue` in that case, to avoid any lifetime issues.

Answer (score 2):

What you register is the base type without any references.

```
qRegisterMetaType<QQueue<double>>();
```

You must also declare the metatype in every compilation unit where it will be used - thus ideally you should have a typedef in its own header file:

```
// DoubleQueue.h
#ifndef DOUBLEQUEUE_H
#define DOUBLEQUEUE_H

#include <QQueue>

typedef QQueue<double> DoubleQueue;
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(DoubleQueue)

#endif
```

Then you must consistently use and register `DoubleQueue` only - remember that for `moc`, a type is a chunk of text. After the references are stripped, it must match exactly.

```
qRegisterMetaType<DoubleQueue>();
```

Comment: Isn't `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` needed only if you intend to use a custom type in `QVariant` or other template-based functions? That's at least what it states in the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmetatype.html#details).

Comment: @thuga That may be true, but the whole point is to show what's needed to use the type anywhere it could be used.

Comment: @thuga but using a queued connection requires the use of QVariant

Comment: @ratchetfreak "using a queued connection requires the use of QVariant" Huh? You can pass any copyable type through a queued connection *without* the use of `QVariant`. That's the whole point of this exercise.

Comment: @KubaOber I meant that Qt uses QVariant behind the scenes for queued connections

Comment: @ratchetfreak No, it doesn't, at least not in the sense of there being any instances of `QVariant` passed around - what's passed around is `QMetaCallEvent`. A keen eye notices distinct absence of `QVariant` from its code. There is some variant-like machinery present, necessarily by the fact that both  `QVariant` and the `QMetaCallEvent` are implemented in terms of the metatype machinery. No code from `QVariant` is directly used. Queued connection code can be, in fact, compiled with without any `QVariant` code being available. That's at least the case in Qt 4/5.