# Qt emitted signal is not received

Tags: c++, qt

I'm not able to receive my custom signal in the supposed `SLOT`. Here is my code:

`mainwindow.h`:

```
class HistoryItem {
    public:
        QString channel;
};


class dbThread : public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT

public:
     dbThread();

signals:

void historyLoaded(QList<HistoryItem*> innerResult);


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void historyLoaded(const QList<HistoryItem*> innerResult);
```

`mainwindow.cpp`:

```
connect(dbtrad, SIGNAL(historyLoaded(QList<HistoryItem*>*)), this, SLOT(historyLoaded(QList<HistoryItem*>*)));

void MainWindow::historyLoaded(QList<HistoryItem*> innerResult) {
    qDebug() << "historyLoaded()...";
}
```

And this is how I emit the signal:

```
QList<HistoryItem*> innerResult;
while (queryInner.next()) {
    QString channelIDInner = queryInner.value(0).toString();

    HistoryItem* item = new HistoryItem();
    item->channel = channelIDInner;

    innerResult.append(item);
}
qDebug() << "DONE LOADING.....";
emit historyLoaded(innerResult);
```

However, `qDebug() << "historyLoaded()...";` is never executed.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422154/my-slot-is-not-invoked-called-used-working-executed

Comment: Are you sure the signal/slot mechanism can handle templates? http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/templates.html

Comment: if you are in Qt5 or up you can use `connect(dbtrad, &dbThread::historyLoaded, this, &MainWindow::historyLoaded);`

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're using threads. Using `QList` when signaling across threads (or using `Qt::QueuedConnection` in general) requires some extra work. Basically you need to define the `QList<T>` type using `typedef` and then register it using `qRegisterMetaType`:

```
typedef QList<HistoryItem*> HistoryList_t;
...
qRegisterMetaType<HistoryList_t>("HistoryList_t");
```

Then use this type in your signals and slots:

```
public slots:
    void historyLoaded(const HistoryList_t &list);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check return value of your `connect`, it should fail. There is an extra `*` in `SIGNAL(historyLoaded(QList<HistoryItem*>*))`, should be `SIGNAL(historyLoaded(QList<HistoryItem*>))`. Fix your `SLOT()` too.

Comment: changed to `connect(dbtrad, SIGNAL(historyLoaded(QList<HistoryItem*>)), this, SLOT(historyLoaded(QList<HistoryItem*>)));` but still same

Comment: Your slot is `historyLoaded(const QList<HistoryItem*>)`. Either remove `const` from slot or add it to signal. And check what your `connect` returns, until it returns `true` your slot won't be triggered.