# Qt: QObject::connect: No such slot QObject::processPendingDatagrams()

Tags: qt

I have written an UDP programme with Qt, and when I connect this:
            `connect(socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(processPendingDatagrams()));`

the complier tells me that 
no such slot

[the error click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbNBg.png)

and I want to know how to fix it, thank you!

P.S.
Here are my files:

[files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FTAH.png)

Here are my codes:

enter code here
**udptest.cpp:**

```
#include "udptest.h"

#include <QObject>

#include <QUdpSocket>

#include <QtNetwork>

UDPtest::UDPtest()
{
    socket = new QUdpSocket();

    port = 2016;
    socket->bind(port,QUdpSocket::ShareAddress
                                    | QUdpSocket::ReuseAddressHint);

       connect(socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(processPendingDatagrams()));

}

QString UDPtest::getIP() 
{
    QList<QHostAddress> list = QNetworkInterface::allAddresses();
    foreach (QHostAddress address, list)
    {
       if(address.protocol() == QAbstractSocket::IPv4Protocol) 
            return address.toString();  
    }
       return 0;
}








void UDPtest::sendMessage(QString message) 
{
    QByteArray data;
    QDataStream out(&data,QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QString localHostName = QHostInfo::localHostName();
    QString address = getIP();
    out <<"123"<< localHostName << address << message;
    socket->writeDatagram(data,data.length(),QHostAddress::Broadcast, port);

}



void UDPtest::processPendingDatagrams() 
{qDebug()<<"receive";
    while(socket->hasPendingDatagrams())
    {
        QByteArray datagram;
        datagram.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());
        socket->readDatagram(datagram.data(),datagram.size());
        QDataStream in(&datagram,QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        QString userName,localHostName,ipAddress,message;
        QString time = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
         in >>userName >>localHostName >>ipAddress >>message;
         QString msg=time+userName+localHostName+ipAddress+message;
         msger=msg;
         qDebug()<<msg;
      }
}

QString UDPtest:: messager()
{
    return msger;
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
    #include"udptest.h"
    #include<QDebug>
    #include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
     qDebug()<<"123";
    UDPtest test;
    test.sendMessage("aha");
    return a.exec();
}
```

**udptest.h:**

```
#ifndef UDPTEST_H
#define UDPTEST_H


#include <QObject>
#include <QUdpSocket>
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtNetwork>

class UDPtest:public QObject
{

public:
    UDPtest();
    QString messager();
void sendMessage(QString);


private slots:
    void processPendingDatagrams();

private:

QString msger;
QUdpSocket *socket;
qint16 port;
QString getIP();

};

#endif // UDPTEST_H
```

**QudptestConsole.pro:**

```
    QT += core
QT -= gui
QT += network
CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = QudptestConsole
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp \
udptest.cpp

HEADERS += \
udptest.h
```

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26422155/1421332

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten `Q_OBJECT` macro in `UDPtest` class

```
class UDPtest: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    UDPtest();

.....
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but when I add the   Q_OBJECT, It shows error : symbol(s) not found for architecture x89_64

Comment: @YOUG Run qmake, then build your project again.