# QObject::connect: No such slot QWidget::makeyourbox() in occQt.cpp:324

Tags: c++, qt5, opencascade

I am new to here.

The ui run well ,but when I click 'okbtn' ...

```
QObject::connect: No such slot QWidget::makeyourbox() in occQt.cpp:324
```

And when I click 'cancelbtn', it runs.

Thanks for any responses,
Eason

code:

```
void occQt::about2()  //UI
{
    QWidget* pWidget = new QWidget;
    QLabel* longlabel = new QLabel(tr("long"));
    QLabel* widthlabel = new QLabel(tr("width"));
    QLabel* highlabel = new QLabel(tr("high"));
    longlineedit = new QLineEdit;
    widthlineedit = new QLineEdit;
    highlineedit = new QLineEdit;
    QPushButton* okbtn = new QPushButton(tr("ok"));
    QPushButton* cancelbtn = new QPushButton(tr("cancel"));
    QGridLayout* gridlayout = new QGridLayout;
    QVBoxLayout* dlglayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    QHBoxLayout* btnlayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    gridlayout->addWidget(longlabel, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    gridlayout->addWidget(widthlabel, 1, 0, 1, 1);
    gridlayout->addWidget(highlabel, 2, 0, 1, 1);
    gridlayout->addWidget(longlineedit, 0, 1, 1, 3);
    gridlayout->addWidget(widthlineedit, 1, 1, 1, 3);
    gridlayout->addWidget(highlineedit, 2, 1, 1, 3);
    longlineedit->setText("5");
    widthlineedit->setText("5");
    highlineedit->setText("5");
    btnlayout->setSpacing(60);
    btnlayout->addWidget(okbtn);
    btnlayout->addWidget(cancelbtn);
    //pWidget->setLayout(gridlayout);
    dlglayout->setMargin(50);
    dlglayout->addLayout(gridlayout);
    dlglayout->addStretch(40);
    dlglayout->addLayout(btnlayout);
    pWidget->setLayout(dlglayout);
    pWidget->setWindowTitle(tr("Make a Box by custom."));
    pWidget->show();
    connect(okbtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), pWidget, SLOT(makeyourbox()));
    //QObject::connect(okbtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), pWidget, SLOT(close()));
    connect(cancelbtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), pWidget, SLOT(close()));
}

void occQt::makeyourbox()
{
    QString string_a = longlineedit->text();
    eason_a = string_a.toInt();
    QString string_b = widthlineedit->text();
    eason_b = string_b.toInt();
    QString string_c = highlineedit->text();
    eason_c = string_c.toInt();
    TopoDS_Shape aTopoBox = BRepPrimAPI_MakeBox(eason_a, eason_b, eason_c).Shape();
    Handle_AIS_Shape anAisBox = new AIS_Shape(aTopoBox);
    anAisBox->SetColor(Quantity_NOC_AZURE);
    mContext->Display(anAisBox);
}
```

When I run the pWidget, click cancelbtn, ui close.
Click okbtn,do nothing..

Comment: please format your code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26422154/1421332

Comment: Thanks you,It solved.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37385409/how-to-add-a-slot-to-a-qwidget/37385551?noredirect=1#comment62281646_37385551

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pWidget is a generic QWidget. It does not contain method/slot makeyourbox().
Your code is faulty.

Comment: Oh... Thank you . I think I get the way.

Answer (score 0):

you should add `makeyourbox()` method to the subclass of `QWidget`, and mark it as slot

Comment: Thanks for your responses, but I don't think it should add...
When adding it , I get the same result..

Comment: My English is poor so I need more time to respond to you,sorry.

Comment: if occQt is subclass of QWidget, you should create an instance of it. This is not working beacause QWidget has no slot with name makeyourbox().

Answer (score 0):

Double check `makeyourbox` is defined to be a slot within that class.