# How to add a slot to a QWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have a QMainWindow, which has a `QAction` whose signal `triggered()` is connected to a slot `about2()`.

```
...
connect(mAboutAction2, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(about2()));
...


void occQt::about2()  //UI
{
    QWidget* pWidget = new QWidget;
    QPushButton* okbtn = new QPushButton(tr("ok"));
    QPushButton* cancelbtn = new QPushButton(tr("cancel"));
    btnlayout->addWidget(okbtn);
    btnlayout->addWidget(cancelbtn);
    dlglayout->setMargin(50);
    dlglayout->addLayout(gridlayout);
    dlglayout->addStretch(40);
    dlglayout->addLayout(btnlayout);
    pWidget->setLayout(dlglayout);
    pWidget->setWindowTitle(tr("Make a Box by custom."));
    pWidget->show();
    connect(okbtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), pWidget, SLOT(make_a_box()));
    connect(cancelbtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), pWidget, SLOT(close()));
}

void occQt::make_a_box()
{
    TopoDS_Shape aTopoBox = BRepPrimAPI_MakeBox(3.0, 4.0, 95.0).Shape();
    Handle_AIS_Shape anAisBox = new AIS_Shape(aTopoBox);

    anAisBox->SetColor(Quantity_NOC_AZURE);

    mContext->Display(anAisBox);
}
```

When I run the slot `about2()`, the UI opens. I can close it when I click the `cancelbtn`, but I can't enter the slot `make_a_box()`.

**Where can I add this slot in order to make this code working?**

Comment: should I need to add a extra .h, and add a slot to the .h ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is ok and runs fine, because the slot you are using is located at the right place : in your `occQt` class.

```
// You connect the signal FROM the action TO "this", i.e. your class
connect(mAboutAction2, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(about2()));

void occQt::about2()  //UI
{

    QWidget* pWidget = new QWidget;
    QPushButton* okbtn = new QPushButton(tr("ok"));
    QPushButton* cancelbtn = new QPushButton(tr("cancel"));
    btnlayout->addWidget(okbtn);
    btnlayout->addWidget(cancelbtn);
    dlglayout->setMargin(50);
    dlglayout->addLayout(gridlayout);
    dlglayout->addStretch(40);
    dlglayout->addLayout(btnlayout);
    pWidget->setLayout(dlglayout);
    pWidget->setWindowTitle(tr("Make a Box by custom."));
    pWidget->show();
```

Now, this is not ok :

```
 // You connect the signal FROM the button to pWidget, which doesn't have a slot make_a_box()
 connect(okbtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), pWidget, SLOT(make_a_box()));
```

The slot `make_a_box()` doesn't exist for `pWidget`, which is a `QWidget`. You are trying to connect a signal to a slot that does not exist.

You have to define this slot in your `occQt` class, **and connect the signal `clicked()` of the button to your slot in your class** :

```
// Now, you connect the signal FROM the button to "this", which is your class and has a slot make_a_box()
connect(okbtn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(make_a_box()));
```

In your .h file, you will have :

```
private slots : 
    void make_a_box();
```

And in your .cpp file :

```
void occQt::make_a_box()
{
    TopoDS_Shape aTopoBox = BRepPrimAPI_MakeBox(3.0, 4.0, 95.0).Shape();
    Handle_AIS_Shape anAisBox = new AIS_Shape(aTopoBox);

    anAisBox->SetColor(Quantity_NOC_AZURE);

    mContext->Display(anAisBox);
}
```

Comment: I have no slot in my pWidget, change pWidget -> this. And it run!