# QObject::connect: No such slot (Qt, C++)

Tags: c++, qt, connect, slot

I can run the program but the button cannot access the send function. I get this hint:

> QObject::connect: No such slot Mail::send(emailInput, pwdInput)

Someone knows what's my mistake?

mail.h:

```
#ifndef MAIL_H
#define MAIL_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class Mail;
}

class Mail : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Mail(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Mail();

public slots:
    void send(std::string email, std::string pwd);

private:
    Ui::Mail *ui;
};

#endif // MAIL_H
```

mail.cpp:

```
Mail::Mail(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{

    QLineEdit *edt1 = new QLineEdit(this);
    grid->addWidget(edt1, 0, 1, 1, 1);
    std::string emailInput = edt1->text().toStdString();
    ...

    QObject::connect(acc, SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(send(emailInput, pwdInput)));
}


void Mail::send(std::string email, std::string pwd){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. You want `SLOT(send(std::string, std::string))`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26422155/1421332

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you have 2 mistakes in your code:

1. the SLOT macro takes the type of arguments as parameter not their name, then the code should be : `SLOT(send(std::string, std::string))`.
2. You try to connect a SIGNAL which has less argument than the SLOT which is impossible.

In order to avoid all these problems you can use the new signal/slot syntax (if your are using Qt5):

```
QObject::connect(acc, &QLineEdit::clicked, this, &Mail::onClicked);
```

I also invite you to use the QString class instead of std::string when working with Qt, it is a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you want to do:

If `emailInput` and `pwdInput` come from widgets, you have to write an intermediate slot that will get the values and call send.

If they are local variables, the easiest is probably to use a lambda.

Comment: just edited the post. I want to save the text in the QLineEdit and then call send with the variables.

Comment: Then you have to write a first slot that takes no parameters and is connected to you button's clicked signal, and calls send with the actual values (or do it in a lambda but it can be messy pretty fast^^)

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
QObject::connect(acc, SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(send(std::string, std::string)));
```

Macros `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` expect method's signature as argument(s).

Additionally, you can connect a signal to a slot of less arity, not the vice versa; here, QObject would not simply know what should be substituted for slot's arguments. You can use the overload of `connect` that accepts an arbitrary `Functor` (an anonymous closure, most likely) as slot:

```
QObject::connect(acc, SIGNAL(clicked()), [=](){ send(std::string(), std::string()); });
```

Thirdly, were you to use `QString` instead of `std::string`, you would not have that heavy copy overhead when passing by value.