# Qt emit signal from a class to class

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals, slots

I've tried to emit a custom signal login() from my loginmanager class to the mainwindow. The signal is fired on the loginButtonClicked slot, and to my understand on the signal/slot mechanism, it should be able to capture any signal fired event and "look" for the corresponding slot to be execute. But it doesn't work as what I've think.

The connect function returns 1, which means it is able to be implemented in the moc file, and it DOES work if i run the m_LoginManager->setLogin() which fires the login() signal.

But what I prefer is the signal is emitted by the loginButton, and pass to the mainwindow to be process (in this case, init()).

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Below are the code.

loginmanager.cpp

```
LoginManager::LoginManager(QWidget * parent) : QWidget(parent) 
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    connect(ui.loginButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(loginButtonClicked());
}

LoginManager::~LoginManager() 
{

}

void LoginManager::setLogin()
{
    emit login();
}

void LoginManager::loginButtonClicked()
{
    setLogin();
}
```

loginmanager.hpp

```
#include <QWidget>
#include "ui_loginmanager.h"

class DatabaseManager;
class SettingManager;

class LoginManager : public QWidget 
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    LoginManager(QWidget * parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    ~LoginManager();

    void setLogin();

signals:
    void login();

public slots:
    void loginButtonClicked();

private:
    Ui::LoginManager ui;
};
```

mainwindow.hpp

```
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_safeboxmanager.h"

class SafeboxManager : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    SafeboxManager(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~SafeboxManager();

public slots:
    void init();

private:
    Ui::SafeboxManagerClass ui;
    LoginManager*       m_LoginManager;
};

#endif // SAFEBOXMANAGER_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "safeboxmanager.hpp"
#include "loginmanager.hpp"

SafeboxManager::SafeboxManager(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    m_LoginManager = new LoginManager();

    ui.mainToolBar->setEnabled(false);
    ui.tableWidget->setEnabled(false);

    connect(m_LoginManager, SIGNAL(login()), this, SLOT(init()));

    //m_LoginManager->setLogin() << this work
}

SafeboxManager::~SafeboxManager()
{

}

void SafeboxManager::init()
{
    ui.mainToolBar->setEnabled(true);
    ui.tableWidget->setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26422154/1421332

Comment: I've read through this. Checked everything (I believe) and the problem still persist. I've read a few people asking about exactly the same issue I'm facing but did not get a proper solution. That's why I decided to ask again hopefully can help the others as well..

Comment: You should check the connect() return values in your code. Also loginButtonClicked() definition lacks the class name.

Comment: As stated in my post, the connect return true. The emit login() is fired but the slot function did not get called. The loginButtonClicked() class name definition is just a typo. I'll edit it.

Comment: Are you sure SafeboxManager isn't destroyed while LoginManager isn't? Check life times.

Comment: SafeboxManager isn't destroyed, not even LoginManager.

Comment: @Silicomancer, seems like you're right. My LoginManager only stores on the stack, so it is destroyed when the main function exits.

Comment: Ok, I made it an actual answer. You should accept it and you should remove the "[SOLVED]" from your question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SafeboxManager and LoginManager objects must live long enough. Check life times.

Comment: I also added this kind of mistake to the signal/slot trouble shooting answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26422155/1421332