# Signal and slot mechanism not working across non-UI threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have the current situation:

[image]

The Worker is a field in the MainWindow class, the Watchdog is a field in the Worker class.

The execution goes like this:

- `Worker` is constructed

  ```
  class Worker : public QThread
  {
      Q_OBJECT
  public:
      explicit Worker();
      void run();

  private:

      Watchdog *watchdog;
      bool running = false;

  signals:
      void tick();

  public slots:
      void ownerDied();
  };
  ```
- The constructor of `Worker` constructs a `Watchdog` on the heap

  ```
  class Watchdog : public QThread
  {

      Q_OBJECT

  public:
      Watchdog();
      void run();

  public slots:

      void tick();

  signals:

      void ownerIsDead();

  };
  ```

  - The constructor does `QObject::connect()` between the `Watchdog` and `Worker` signals and slots

    ```
    connect(this, SIGNAL(tick()), watchdog, SLOT(tick()));
    connect(watchdog, SIGNAL(ownerIsDead()), this, SLOT(ownerDied()));
    ```
  - The main loop of the `Worker` starts in the `Worker::run()` method.
  - The `Worker` starts the `Watchdog`. The `Watchdog` loop is started.
  - If the `Worker` does not `tick()` within 5 seconds of the `start()` call, the `Watchdog` emits the `ownerIsDead()` signal
  - Worker processes the `ownerDied()` signal, killing the main `Worker` loop
  - If the `Worker` does tick the `Watchdog`, he sleeps another 5 seconds
  - The whole process repeats

The problem is, the `tick()` never reaches the `Watchdog`, nor does the `ownerIsDead()` signal reach the worker because it did not tick. Why?

Here is the raw code, the class names are a bit different.

**watchdog.h**

```
#ifndef WATCHDOG_H
#define WATCHDOG_H

#define THRESHOLD 1000

#include <QThread>
#include <QObject>

class Watchdog : public QThread
{

    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Watchdog();
    void run();

public slots:

    void tick();
    void kill();

private:

    bool running = false;
    bool ticked = false;

signals:

    void error();

};

#endif // WATCHDOG_H
```

**watchdog.cpp**

```
#include "watchdog.h"

#include <QDebug>

Watchdog::Watchdog()
{

}

void Watchdog::run()
{

    running = true;

    qDebug() << "Starting watchdog";

    while (running) {

        QThread::msleep(THRESHOLD);

        qDebug() << "Watchdog tick ... ";

        if (!ticked) {
            qDebug() << "read() or write() is read";
            emit error();
        }
    }

}

void Watchdog::tick()
{
    qDebug() << "Watchdog ticking";

    ticked = true;

}

void Watchdog::kill()
{

    qDebug() << "Killing watchdog...";

    running = false;

}
```

**diskerror.h** ( AKA the 'Worker' )

```
#ifndef DISKERROR_H
#define DISKERROR_H

#include <QThread>
#include <watchdog.h>

extern "C" {

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <malloc.h>

}

class DiskError : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DiskError();
    void run();

private:
    int mismatch(char *a, char *b);
    Watchdog *watchdog;
    bool running = false;

signals:
    void tick();
    void killWatchdog();

public slots:
    void ownerIsDead();
};

#endif // DISKERROR_H
```

**diskerror.cpp**

```
include "diskerror.h"

#include "watchdog.h"

#include <QDebug>

#define BLKSZ 4096

DiskError::DiskError()
{

    watchdog = new Watchdog();

    connect(this, SIGNAL(killWatchdog()), watchdog, SLOT(kill()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(tick()), watchdog, SLOT(tick()));
    connect(watchdog, SIGNAL(error()), this, SLOT(ownerIsDead()));

}

void DiskError::run()
{


    int fd = open("/dev/sdc", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);

    if (fd < 0) {
        qDebug() << strerror(errno);
    }

    size_t size;

    if (ioctl(fd, BLKGETSIZE64, &size) < 0) {
        qDebug() << "IOCTL Error";
        return;
    }


    size_t step = (size / 2500);
    size_t done = 0;

    int i = 0;

    char testing[BLKSZ];
    char pattern[BLKSZ];


    for (int i = 0; i < BLKSZ; i++) {
        pattern[i] = 0xCF;
    }

    int re, bb, wr;

    off_t curr = 0;

    watchdog->start();
    running = true;

    while (running) {

        lseek(fd, curr, SEEK_SET);

        wr = write(fd, pattern, BLKSZ); /* Write pattern to disk */

        lseek(fd, curr, SEEK_SET);

        re = read(fd, testing, BLKSZ); /* Read pattern back from disk */

        bb = mismatch(pattern, testing);

        curr += BLKSZ;
        done += BLKSZ;

        emit tick();

        if ( (re == 0) || (wr < 0) ) {

            qDebug() << "Flushing buffers...";

            sync();

            break;
        }

        if (done >= step) {

            if (bb) {
                qDebug() << "[" << i << "] Error occured";
            } else {
                qDebug() << "[" << i << "] OK";
            }


            done = 0;
            i++;

        }

    }

    emit killWatchdog();

    sync();

    if (close(fd) < 0) {
        qDebug() << "Error closing device";
    }

}

int DiskError::mismatch(char *a, char *b)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < BLKSZ; i++) {
        if (  (*(a+i)) != (*(b+i))  ) return 1;
    }

    return 0;

}

void DiskError::ownerIsDead()
{
    qDebug() << "read() call blocked for more than 5 seconds, device inoperable";
}
```

I never see the debug text in the worker class, nor do I see the tick text in the worker.

Comment: You need to run an event loop in each thread, where you want to handle slots. In your `Watchdog` class you don't need to override run method with an infinite loop. Instead you need to create an object with timer in this thread.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422154/my-signal-slot-connection-does-not-work

Answer (score 2):

What could be happening is that the receiver object "belongs" to a different thread than the one doing the emit.

This kind of cross-thread signal/slot connections, so called `Qt::QueuedConnection` connections, require a running event loop in the thread of the receiver object.

If the receiver object has been created by one of the additional threads, then this thread needs to run its event loop, see `QThread::exec()`

Not sure you actually need the watchdog to be a separate thread, it seems in only checks a condition in regular intervals, something a `QTimer` on the main thread could easily do as well.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in previous comments and answers by other guys, I think the central problem is that you have no event loop in your "threads", which is the responsible of managing (check, elaborate and do actions according) signals/slots. Also infinite loop is the worst thing to do, because it prevent your thread/application to "call" the event loop, so that signal/slot system becomes useless.
You can find a more clear and extensive explenation here: https://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects

A trick to allow your while loop working with signal/slot is to call at each iteration the function *QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlags flags)*. From Qt docs:

> Processes all pending events for the calling thread according to the
>   specified flags until there are no more events to process.
>
> You can call this function occasionally when your program is busy
>   performing a long operation (e.g. copying a file).
>
> In event you are running a local loop which calls this function
>   continuously, without an event loop, the DeferredDelete events will
>   not be processed. This can affect the behaviour of widgets, e.g.
>   QToolTip, that rely on DeferredDelete events to function properly. An
>   alternative would be to call sendPostedEvents() from within that local
>   loop.
>
> Calling this function processes events only for the calling thread.

One last comment: the way you have implemented threading is not wrong, but is also not the way Qt suggests (but maybe the one you have choosen knowing what I'm saying). In fact, QThread objects are not the threads, but the objects managing threads. More information about this at this link of Qt docs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qthread.html#details