# Qt - No matching function for connect?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to connect a signal and a slot. I had it working, but I accidentally deleted a .h file. Now I tried to rewrite it, and everything's gone to hell. I've got:

```
#ifndef GAMEMANAGER_H
#define GAMEMANAGER_H

#include "gamepersistence.h"

class GameManager
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    GameManager();
    ~GameManager();

    GamePersistence* _gamePersistece;
// other stuff
 signals:
    void refreshPlease();
    void gameOverSignal();
};

#endif // GAMEMANAGER_H
```

And then I'm trying to connect it in another class:

```
GameWindow::GameWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    setFixedSize(900,200);
    setWindowTitle(trUtf8("Amőba"));

    //this->setStyleSheet("background-color: white;");
    _gameManager = new GameManager();
//    _gameManager->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
    connect(_gameManager, SIGNAL(gameOverSignal()), this, SLOT(gameOver()));
    connect(_gameManager, SIGNAL(refreshPlease()), this, SLOT(refreshTable()));
//other stuff
}
```

This is in a class called GameWindow. Now I'm getting errors for the two connect lines:

`error: no matching function for call to 'GameWindow::connect(GameManager*&, const char*, GameWindow* const, const char*)'
     connect(_gameManager, SIGNAL(gameOverSignal()), this, SLOT(gameOver()));`

What did I mess up in the header? I think I've rewritten it as it was...

Comment: Use version control systems ;)

Comment: Can't use slots and signals in a class that doesn't derive from `QObject`.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out 5 mins ago :)

Comment: This is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26422155/1421332

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, I have to use the `: public QObject` base class.

Answer (score -1):

in gamemanager.h add the public inheritance from QObject for signal and slot can be called.

```
class GameManager : public QObject{ //your class definition };
```